# When do units say their annoyed quotes?

Tags: starcraft-2

When looking up SC2 units on Liquipedia, I noticed that there are a number of categories of quotes for each unit. Most of these are self explanatory as to when they play, but I'm not sure when the "annoyed" quotes are triggered.

When do the units say these quotes?

Comment: What kind of "annoyed" quotes?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to click the units a lot of times in a row. If you do it for a while, they will become annoyed and say those quotes.

Comment: No point writing another answer when this one's clear enough, but I'll add the commonly known piece of trivia that those hidden lines are present in every Blizzard game, and are always triggered the same way, i.e. by repeated clicking.

Comment: My favorite instance of clicking repeatedly to get a joke is in WC3, where you'd click neutral pigs repeatedly and eventually they'd explode.

Comment: That was true for every critter in SC1 :D

Comment: @StrixVaria: This works only in single player though.

Comment: In WC2 the sheep would say "Baa Ram Eweeeeee" before they exploded... it was pretty sweet...

Comment: In SC2 critters explode even in multiplayer. Just click repeatedly.